# Session Log Out Issue

Tags: asp.net, session, ccavenue

There is web application which is created on asp.net.
This application works perfectly when i run this on my local.
I have used session to store the userId of the user in the session.
In every page where i want only logged in user to be able to enter i have written code like.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["userID"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
            }
        }

    }
```

So when session does not have userID user gets automatically redirected to login page.

I am facing two problems
1.When I deploy it to BigRock shared server.User automatically gets logged out in 5 minutes.It is defined session time out set in that server which I can not change. I do not want my user to get logged out automatically.

2.Payment Gateway is also integrated with this website and when the user clicks on check out .He gets redirected to payment gateway but when after entering his payment details and transaction completes when he gets back to response page ,he again automatically gets logged out whether 5 minutes was completed or not.This also works fine when I test this for the condition when I run this website on my local.

Every help is appreciated.Thank You So much in advanced!

Please let me know if you need any more clarification or source code.

Comment: did you try configuring the timeout in web.config?

Comment: Yes I tried doing that...

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can always try logging back the user based on the order-id received from PG. Since the response from PG is usually protected by checksum, you can rely on it's authenticity to carry back the user to your page. Just update your login session by using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` method to re-login the user.

In your case since your directly assigning userdId to Session (IMHO, not the best way to manage logins though. Try searching for `MembershipProvider`), the steps are pretty straight forward.

1. Get the OrderId from PG response.
2. Fetch the associated userId from Orders table (For this you must have associated each user with their orders.
3. Save the userId in Session.
4. Redirect the user to secure page.

Why are we not asking for password? Because, responses from PG are usually protected by means of hashing and usually immune to tampering. So you can safely bet on the authenticity of the user redirected by PG.

Comment: Can you please provide an example How to do that..I am new to this and never used this FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie before

Comment: How are you logging in the users? Are you using the in-built "Login Control" or have you created your own login form?

Comment: I have created my own login form